# Comparing Data Frames and getting the differences with Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames as shown below. Where we have hours for a project by resources.
One was the info about 10 days ago & the other is as of today.
I want to find ONLY the differences between these two data frames (Resource & project both teed to considered while performing the difference). For example for PN8, Mat had 8 previously but now, it is 16, so the result should be PN13--Mat--8. PN22 in completely new, so, it should be completely as it is in the new Daataframe (PN22--Sid--2). Some resources were there before but now now (like Raja). Some resources were NOT there before but are there now (like Ann). Both these should be in the new Dataframe.

I tried to do a direct comparison `df1 != df2` but i get an error that labels are different even though they are exactly the same. Can you help?

[image]
 [image].

Comment: Mat had 8 previously or 14 ?

Comment: You are right, it was 14 previously, now 16.

Answer (score 0):

To compare and compute the difference, first set the indices of the data frames to be the `PR No.` and `Resource` columns. Combine the data frames using `append`. Then, group by index (which is the combination of `PR No.` and `Resource`) and compute the difference within each group. This will generate NaNs in the groups containing two values, they are not needed so, the `dropna` function takes care of that. Finally, call `reset_index` to bring back `PR No.` and `Resource` as columns.

```
# setup
data1 = [
    ["PN1", "Chris", 1],
    ["PN2", "Julie", 80],
    ["PN3", "John", 2.4],
    ["PN4", "Steve", 2]
]

data2 = [
    ["PN1", "Chris", 11],
    ["PN2", "Julie", 76],
    ["PN8", "John", 2.4],
    ["PN9", "Jonas", 2]
]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ["PR No.", "Resource", "hours"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ["PR No.", "Resource", "hours"])

print(df1)
print(df2)

# solution
group_by_cols = ["PR No.", "Resource"]
indexed_by_group_cols_1 = df1.set_index(group_by_cols)
indexed_by_group_cols_2 = df2.set_index(group_by_cols)
appended = indexed_by_group_cols_1.append(indexed_by_group_cols_2)
grouped_by_index = appended.groupby(appended.index)

compare_diff = grouped_by_index.apply(lambda x: x.diff() if len(x) > 1 else x) \
    .dropna().reset_index()

print(compare_diff)
```

Output:

DF1:

```
  PR No. resource  hours
0    PN1    Chris    1.0
1    PN2    Julie   80.0
2    PN3     John    2.4
3    PN4    Steve    2.0
```

DF2:

```
  PR No. resource  hours
0    PN1    Chris   11.0
1    PN2    Julie   76.0
2    PN8     John    2.4
3    PN9    Jonas    2.0
```

Result:

```
  PR No. resource  hours
0    PN1    Chris   10.0
1    PN2    Julie   -4.0
2    PN3     John    2.4
3    PN4    Steve    2.0
4    PN8     John    2.4
5    PN9    Jonas    2.0
```